# Cannot Parse Paypal Date Correctly

Tags: php, paypal

Here are the variables inside my ipn:

```
$paymentdate = $_POST['payment_date'];
$mdate= date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($paymentdate));
```

$paymentdate inserts to table like: Mon May 11 2015 13:01:36 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula...

$mdate inserts to table like: 1969-12-31 05:00:00

As you can see $mdate comes out with wrong date and time.

I am trying to get the correct $payment_date to add to the database with the format of Y-m-d h:i:s.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "way off"

Comment: For example the date comes out like: 1684-03-16 12:00:00

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put this information inside (specifying source `$paymentdate` and result in `$mdate`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. I'm able to get proper date format by this line of code. $edata['payment_date']  = date("M d, Y", strtotime($content['payment_date']));

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution Your format gives me the following:

31 12, 1969